# sflow calculate bps per src/dst ip in ClickHouse

Tags: clickhouse

I collect sflow with goflow2 and use ClickHouse to store this data.
And now, I'm trying to do some basics graph.
For example, I want to draw graph bits/s per SrcIp.
I try to use this query, but with real flow of 200 Mbps, I got graph that shows me ~2 Gbps.

```
SELECT
    toUInt64(toStartOfMinute($dateTimeCol))*1000 as t,
    sum(Bytes*SamplingRate) as sumbytes
FROM $table
WHERE $timeFilter and IPv4NumToString(reinterpretAsUInt32(substring(reverse(SrcAddr), 13,4))) like '195.78.38.190'
GROUP BY t
ORDER BY t
```

I need something like irate in Prometheus, but in Prometheus we got counters and its easy to calculate what I need.

Comment: Convert to bps by `*8/60`. Enjoy.

Comment: Maybe you should try https://victoriametrics.com/

Comment: I posted that as an answer so this can be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is correct but returns bytes instead of bps.

Since your aggregating per minute, you need to divide by 60 seconds so you have bytes per second. Byte is 8 bits so multiply by that to get bits.

`/ 60 * 8`

```sql
SELECT
    toUInt64(toStartOfMinute($dateTimeCol))*1000 as t,
    sum(Bytes*SamplingRate) * 8 / 60 as sumbytes
FROM $table
WHERE $timeFilter and IPv4NumToString(reinterpretAsUInt32(substring(reverse(SrcAddr), 13,4))) like '195.78.38.190'
GROUP BY t
ORDER BY t
```